# Intermediate steps of this matrix equality?

Tags: matrices, optimization, matrix-equations

In my current studies, I have come across the following reformulation:

$$\matrix{min \\ c}\frac{1}{2N}||Ac+Bd||^2_2 \Leftrightarrow c^*=-\left(A^\top A\right)^{-1}\left(A^\top Bd\right)$$

where $c^*$ is the $c$ which minimizes the LHS expression. The terms are defined as follows:

- $A$ is a $N\times D$ matrix
- $B$ is a $N\times E$ matrix
- $c$ is a $D\times 1$ vector
- $d$ is a $E\times 1$ vector
- $N$ is an integer

All variables are real. Unfortunately, no intermediate steps are provided. How does the RHS follow from the LHS?

Comment: You can prove the existence of the minimum, and then obtain its expression by noticing that it has to be a critical point (ie a point where the derivative of the LHS vanishes).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to minimize the norm of a real vector $M x + b$ over $x$ you can require the first-order conditions that the derivative with respect to $x$ of the square of the norm vanishes. That is:

$$\nabla_x (M x + b)^2=\nabla_x (b^T b + 2 x^T M^T b + x M^T M x) = 2 \left(M^T b + M^T M x \right) = 0.$$

From this, your result follows when $A^T A$ is invertible, which it isn't always (as a counter-example, consider $A=0$).

Comment: That's it, thank you!

Comment: Glad it was helpful! I just went over the same calculation with some students this afternoon, for least-squares minimization.